# In App purchase consultation

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm building a new application that should contain in app purchases.

I follow the XCode Tutorial: In-App Purchase (by simple sdk) video at youtube. The tutorial is  about downloading an audio file, but my project is based on executing a HTTP request. Can you help me set up methods to do this?

Note: Apple improved purchasing when download is complete, but in my case there is no download. So how to make Apple improve that purchasing is complete.

Comment: the user should have the possibility to purchase package (execute link) many time i have create the application in app as consumable

Answer (score 1):

Verify that a payment has been made.
Use the 'hidden' command to show a button. You tube will have many examples on how to hide and show buttons.
Lastly, have an action for this button
that when tapped it executes your HTTP request ..

Answer (score 0):

No one will write your code for you here. But here is a great tutorial: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Try it and if you have questions you can ask them here.